# How to use PHAsset to get [PHAssetCollection]

Tags: ios, swift, photo

I can get all the photos, but I do not know how to find the albums in which these photos are located.
Another option is to go through all the albums and get photos from them.
I think this is not a good option.
The goal is to get the name of the albums for each photo.

```
    private func getPhotosAll() -> [String:Photo] {
        var photos = [String:Photo]()
        let assets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: nil)
        assets.enumerateObjects({ (asset, index, stop) in
            let id = asset.localIdentifier
            guard (id.isEmpty == false) else {
                return
            }
            guard let name = asset.originalFilename else {
                return
            }
            let photo = Photo()
            photo.name = name
            // TODO: Read albums?
            photo.albums = [String]()
            photos[id] = photo
        })
        return photos
    }
```

Update. I get only user albums. And how to get the rest? (Camera Roll, People, Places, Recently Deleted)

```
var albums = Set<String>()
let typesAlbum: [PHAssetCollectionType] = [.album, .smartAlbum, .moment]
for type in typesAlbum {
    let collectionsBox = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollectionsContaining(asset,
            with: type, options: nil)
    collectionsBox.enumerateObjects { (collection, _, _) in
        guard let albumName = collection.localizedTitle else {
            return
        }
        albums.insert(albumName)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For each PHAsset, call [`fetchAssetCollectionsContaining(_:with:options:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phassetcollection/1618530-fetchassetcollectionscontaining).

Comment: Can I be sure that by specifying [.album, .smartAlbum, .moment], will I get all the albums from the photo?